# Not binding path in datagrid (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

type of column in datagrid is combobox, i create List, and list this ok, bit if i write in xaml

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=combolist}"
```

items is null
my list

```
List<string> combolist = new List<string>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                combolist.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
```

why items is null?

Comment: do you have property combolist? what is datacontext of your view?

Comment: where do you declare the `combolist`, is it a property or field? what is the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox`? please give us more info

Comment: without datacontext the combobox dont care about your binding :)

Comment: @MexVI List is fine - what's wrong with list?

Comment: Not everyone needs property changed notification - especially when trying to bind to a private member :D

Answer (score 0):

combolist must be property. It should be inside [View Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). (IMO, it should be `ComboList`).

Answer (score 0):

binding just work for **public Properties**.

```
  public List<string> Combolist {get;set}

  //ctor
  this.Combolist = new List<string>();
  while (reader.Read())
        {
            Combolist .Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }

  this.DataContext = this;
```

!if you do not fill your list in the ctor, you should use ObservableCollection instead of list.