# Wrong list, not binding in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not binding path in datagrid (wpf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409540/not-binding-path-in-datagrid-wpf)

combobox in datagrid!!! **ahtung!**

```
 <ComboBox Name="mex" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=combolist}" SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
</ComboBox>
```

so

```
MySqlCommand status_db = new MySqlCommand("select name_ru from request_status", conn);
MySqlDataReader combodata = status_db.ExecuteReader();
List<string> combolist = new List<string>();
  while (combodata.Read())
  {
     combolist.Add(combodata.GetString(0));
  }
```

why items in combobox empty? I'm going crazy!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `RelativeSource Self` for your DataContext, which means that the DataContext will be the ComboBox itself. When binding the ItemsSource, it will try to find a property of the ComboBox named combolist (which of course doesn't exist).

To fix the problem, you can either

- change the DataContext of your ComboBox to be your control (or window, page, ...) and make the list a property of the control.
- set the ItemsSource directly in code behind: `mex.ItemsSource = combolist`