# Binding ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

**I did everything right?**

```
public List<string> combolist { get; set; }
```

...

```
this.combolist = new List<string>();
MySqlCommand status_db = new MySqlCommand("select name_ru from request_status", conn);
MySqlDataReader combodata = status_db.ExecuteReader();
   while (combodata.Read())
   {
     combolist.Add(combodata.GetString(0));
   }
   this.DataContext = this;
```

in xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=combolist}"...
```

but items the combobox is empty, what's wrong?

Comment: do not ask 3 times the same question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong list, not binding in combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412934/wrong-list-not-binding-in-combobox)

Comment: -1 for asking the same question 4 times. Please look into what has been suggested in previous questions and if you have more questions regarding the same topic, please ask in the same thread in comments or through edits.

Comment: Did you set the DataContext right? Are you even using ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ObservableCollection.  Instantiate the ObservableCollection before you call InitializeComponent()

Answer (score 0):

this works:

usercontrol1.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Combolist}" />
</Grid>
```

usercontrol1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Combolist { get; private set; }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        this.Combolist = new ObservableCollection<string>();//just initialize once!
        InitializeComponent();
        //if you wanna load new data, call .Clear() before
        //this.Combolist.Clear();
        //MySqlCommand status_db = new MySqlCommand("select name_ru from request_status", conn);
        //MySqlDataReader combodata = status_db.ExecuteReader();
        //while (combodata.Read())
        //{
        //    Combolist.Add(combodata.GetString(0));
        //}

        //test
        this.Combolist.Add("qqqq");
        this.Combolist.Add("wwww");
        this.Combolist.Add("eeee");
        this.Combolist.Add("rrrr");

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MexVI i know that this will not help you because you wanna know how it works within a DataGridTemplateColumn/DataGridComboboxColumn, but as long as you ask your question 3 or more times here and dont even use the search function for your problem, no one can help you right.

Comment: blindmeis you code not work! i`m not stupid! if use you code in sample combobox - yes, here work, but if combobox in datagrid - not work! WHY!!!???

Comment: because there is another datacontext! thats why. try using the search function this problem is multiple times answered here on stackoverflow. just search after: wpd datagridtemplatecolumn combobox binding